# Use a Blob URI as destiny URI in jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Well...** I am trying to make a AJAX Request with jQuery AJAX where the destiny URI is a Blob URI, the code is this:

```
<input type="file">
<script>
  $('input').change(function (event) {
    var pathsito = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    window.open(pathsito);
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: pathsito,
  data:{
    myData:"Cool!"
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  alert("Returned Text: " + data);
});
  })
</script>
```

The result of this code: nothing, literally, it do not make nothing , a solution, please